# Am I allowed to tell someone I upvoted them?

Tags: discussion, up-votes, comments

Can I tell someone I upvoted them? I completely know that we'll get booted if we try bribery, but can I just post a comment something like, "Great answer! I gave you an upvote for the time you obviously spent on this!"

Comment: Bribery is actually welcome in the form of [bounties](http://photo.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, most often you see this in the form of "+1 < Comment about why its awesome. >"